# Como armazenar imagens dentro da aplicação?

Tags: java, imagem

Estou começando agora em Java e preciso terminar uma aplicação que ao clicar em um botão mostre uma imagem, eu até consegui fazer isso usando o método

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File()
 mas eu precisava que esse programa funcionasse em qualquer computador, teria como colocar a imagem dentro da própria aplicação ou algo assim? 
Obrigado

Comment: Se o usuário da sua aplicação tem a opção de cadastrar imagens, salve o caminho onde ela está, e depois quando for visualizar, busque pelo caminho o qual salvou.

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que vc já fez para capturar e/ou pegar o caminho da imagem? Assim fica mais fácil de podermos ajudar! Saberemos qual caminho tomar! Obrigago

Comment: Estou fazendo assim http://imgur.com/Lu2RFPP

Answer (score 0):

Pode colocar a imagem numa pasta e depois ao gerar o jar gera com a pasta tambem

Comment: mas ai eu coloco qual caminho no código? o caminho onde a pasta está no meu computador?